# adding group mean to the geom_point() in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I was wondering if I could add (overlay) the `mean` of each column of points (using different shapes, e.g., rectangles, squares, triangles etc.) to the plot below?

```
library(ggplot2)
hsb <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rnorouzian/e/master/hsb.csv')
ten <- subset(hsb, sch.id %in% unique(sch.id)[1:10]) # get 10 schools for display
ten %>% ggplot() + aes(meanses, math) + geom_point() + geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll demonstrate a starting *method*, but it's flawed in that I infer that rounding `meanses` is sufficient to keep things grouped correctly. If it is not always this "clean", then you will likely need some cheap clustering in there as well.

```r
means <- group_by(ten, g = format(round(meanses, 1))) %>%
  summarize(meanses = first(meanses), math = mean(math))
ggplot(ten, aes(meanses, math)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE) +
  geom_point(data = means, aes(shape = g), color = "red", size = 5)
# `geom_smooth()` using formula 'y ~ x'
# Warning: The shape palette can deal with a maximum of 6 discrete values because more than 6 becomes
# difficult to discriminate; you have 7. Consider specifying shapes manually if you must
# have them.
# Warning: Removed 1 rows containing missing values (geom_point).
```

(We also need a few more shapes ... `scale_shape_manual` is likely required.)

[image: ggplot2 with group averages]

---

A quick way to find the groups here:

```r
grps <- sort(unique(round(ten$meanses, 3)))
grps[c(FALSE, diff(grps) < 0.01)] <- NA
grps <- grps[!is.na(grps)]
means <- ten %>%
  group_by(grp = format(grps[ apply(abs(outer(meanses, grps, `-`)), 1, which.min) ])) %>%
  summarize(meanses = first(meanses), math = mean(math)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

(It still has the same problem with the number of shapes, but that's easily worked around.)